# Xamarin Forms: set minimum height of label in ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have created a xamarin forms pcl project. In that I have used a label with font size 30 but when I tried using hindi language font, some part of text is cutting from bottom so that I tried specifying minimum height of label but it seems to have no effect.

For specifying minimum height, I have created a custom label.

In Android:-
`this.Control.SetMinimumHeight(80);`

In Windows:- 
`Control.MinHeight = 40;`

In ios, I want to know how can I give a label minimum height.

Comment: @Gerald Versluis i have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the label, natively from Xamarin.iOS with a Custom Renderer, just place this file in your native Xamarin.iOS project and it will run for every label you have in Xamarin Forms.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(LabelRender))]
namespace Mobile.iOS.CustomRenderers
{
    public class LabelRender: LabelRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Font = ... // Or whatever you want to change.
            }                   

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For height which property can I use?

Comment: Minimum height???

Comment: Height will be determined by the font size.

Comment: I want to specify minimum height for some reasons as I am facing issues with hindi font.